# $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] Not Working

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to access a file hosted on my server, offcourse outside public_html folder. Code to access the ini file is given below:

```
$config = parse_ini_file($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."../credentials.ini");
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost",$config['username'],$config['password']);
```

The error:

```
Warning: parse_ini_file(/home2/gaurav/public_html/fantacy.co.in../credentials.ini): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home2/gaurav/public_html/fantacy.co.in/DB_CONNECT.php on line 23
```

Comment: Well it's working, you're just not accessing the correct path..

Comment: Look at the warning message! You're missing a / (at least).

Comment: Confused, please point out. Don't play. If I found it earlier, I wouldn't have posted it here.

Comment: Look where your string (credentials) comes back into play in the error message, and you tell me id that's a correct path..?

Comment: it is not coming out of the 'fantacy.co.in' folder

Comment: this is the correct path.../home2/gaurav/public_html/credentials.ini

Comment: Which is not the same as `/home2/gaurav/public_html/fantacy.co.in../credentials.ini` is it. Again, missing a /.

Comment: NO/home2/gaurav/public_html/credentials.ini

Comment: Let's try another way. You're folder is called `fantacy.co.in` not `fantacy.co.in..` right?

Comment: yes.. I want to come one step back of the folder...

Comment: Oh my dear lord... `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/../credentials.ini"`

Comment: Arggg... I tried it..  Warning: parse_ini_file(/home2/gaurav/public_html/fantacy.co.in/../credentials.ini)

Comment: please try this one: `$config = parse_ini_file("../".$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "credentials.ini");`

Comment: naa.. already tried.

Comment: I think i finally got it, use this one: $config = parse_ini_file(dirname($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'])."/credentials.ini");

Comment: BINGOO!! SOLVED. Thank you everyone for brainstorming with me. @TarunMahashwari thank you.

Comment: So the information you gave us was wrong... useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$config = parse_ini_file(dirname($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'])."/credentials.ini");
```

Answer (score 2):

You've missed **/**

```
$config = parse_ini_file($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/../credentials.ini");
```

Comment: No.. that is not right.. Nor error is.... Warning: parse_ini_file(/home2/gaurav/public_html/fantacy.co.in/../credentials.ini)

Comment: It is mentioned in the comment above you... second line.

Comment: There should be more to the warning than just that line.

Comment: are you sure that the file `/home2/gaurav/public_html/fantacy.co.in/../credentials.ini` is there ??
please type this command in your terminal 
`head /home2/gaurav/public_html/fantacy.co.in/../credentials.ini` and see what's happen

Comment: file is here... /home2/gaurav/public_html/credentials.ini           and it is hosted on webserver...

Comment: finally the file wasn't there...you didn't type the command in terminal... :(